# Aggregating data frame rows using an input vector

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have this toy `data.frame`:

```
df = data.frame(id = c("a","b","c","d"), value = c(2,3,6,5))
```

and I'd like to aggregate its rows according to this toy vector:

```
collapsed.ids = c("a,b","c","d")
```

where the aggregated data.frame should keep `max(df$value)` of its aggregated rows.

So for this toy example the output would be:

```
> aggregated.df
   id value
1 a,b     3
2   c     6
3   d     5
```

I should note that my real data.frame is ~150,000 rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `data.table` for this.

Something like the following should work:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df, key = "id")       # Main data.table
Key <- data.table(ind = collapsed.ids) # your "Key" table
## We need your "Key" table in a long form
Key <- Key[, list(id = unlist(strsplit(ind, ",", fixed = TRUE))), by = ind]
setkey(Key, id)                        # Set the key to facilitate a merge
## Merge and aggregate in one step
DT[Key][, list(value = max(value)), by = ind]
#    ind value
# 1: a,b     3
# 2:   c     6
# 3:   d     5
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `data.table`, you can just use base R.

```
split.ids <- strsplit(collapsed.ids, ",")
split.df <- data.frame(id = tmp <- unlist(split.ids),
                       joinid = rep(collapsed.ids, sapply(split.ids, length)))
aggregated.df <- aggregate(value ~ id, data = merge(df, split.df), max)
```

Result:

```
#    id value
# 1 a,b     3
# 2   c     6
# 3   d     5
```

### Benchmark

```
df <- df[rep(1:4, 50000), ] # Make a big data.frame
system.time(...) # of the above code
#   user  system elapsed
#  1.700   0.154   1.947
```

EDIT: Apparently Ananda's code runs in 0.039, so I'm eating crow. But either are acceptable for this size.